# How to use classifier random forest in Python for 2 different data sets?

Tags: python, random-forest

I have 2 data sets with different variables.  But both includes a variable, say NUM, that helps to identify the occurrence of an event. With the NUM, I was able to identify the event, by labelling it. How can one run RF to effectively include considerations of the 2 datasets? I am not able to append them (column wise) as the number of records for each NUM differs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow

Comment: Are all columns independent, or are there columns that are present in both data sets, even if with different data (say, both have a column called 'weight')?

Comment: The columns are distinct (with different names) apart from NUM which is common in both data sets. NUM acts a identifier of sorts.

Comment: @chris, so `NUM` is what you are trying to predict? In that case, what is the benefit of trying to use a single classifier, when it appears that you have two different, distinct datasets?

Comment: There are a few known instances of NUM (say 8, 121, 200) where NUM can range from 1 to 300, for example, that result in an event. I am making use of NUM to identify the occurrence of the event. This is somewhat like anamoly detection. There could be 100 records of NUM 8 in the first dataset and 200 records of NUM 8 in the 2nd dataset with a different set of variables.

Answer (score 1):

From the way your question is phrased, I'm guessing you have two pandas dataframes.

You can use pandas.merge to pull the two together. All you need to do is a join of some sort. Left might be what you're looking for, but if you want to only pull data where you have a NUM value in both dataframes, use an inner join.

See the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Here's how that might look:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',left_on='NUM')
```

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for the suggestion. I could do that but would invariably lose some of the data in the both or the 2nd data sets.

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at. Have you tried combining the two dataframes and then performing a groupby on the NUM column? If that's not what you're looking for, then maybe just performing a df.loc would do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put NUM as a single column, and the first and second datasets would use completely independent columns, with the non-matching cells containing empty data. Whether the results will be any good, will depend much on your data.